# How should I publish an arcgis toolbox via arcobjects (c#)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-runtime

I've been able to create map and image services by creating, adding, and starting configurations through an IServerObjectAdmin interface to a version 10.0 (sp4) ArcGIS server. Now, I'm shifting my focus to publishing toolboxes as GPServer configurations. I'm referring to the existing cfg file (found here ArcGIS\Server10.0\server\user\cfg) and setting properties exactly as found in this file. Regardless, when I try to add the configuration, I get an RPC failure exception and the SOM service on the targeted server has crashed. I'll include some stripped-down sample code to show how I'm going about adding configurations. I'd appreciate any ideas on how I could better go about publishing a geoprocessing toolbox. The underlying goal is to quickly replicate services from a failing (or failed) ArcGIS server onto another server to decrease downtime.

```
 ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
 IGISServerConnection gisServerConnection = new GISServerConnection();
 gisServerConnection.Connect(ServerName);
 _serverObjectAdmin = gisServerConnection.ServerObjectAdmin;
 var config = _serverObjectAdmin.CreateConfiguration();
 // set config settings and other properties here
 var config2 = (IServerObjectConfiguration2)config;  
 // set other settings accessible via Configuration2 interface
 _serverObjectAdmin.AddConfiguration(config2);
 _serverObjectAdmin.StartConfiguration("folder/service", "GPServer");
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the server's log file?

Comment: Not really, last message before I restart the crashed SOM service is "attempting to add configuration XX/XX of type GPServer" XX/XX is folder and service name. I've verified that I can publish the toolbox via the right-click menu in Catalog

Comment: Ryan, Were you ever able to come up with a solution to this problem

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I stopped looking after I exhausted all of my leads. I'm okay with publishing toolboxes manually since we don't have all that many. I'd be really interested to hear any other possible methods that you may encounter, though.

Answer (score 1):

I filed a ticket with ESRI support over this matter and found that they do not support publishing C# executables as a GPService in 10.1.

Quite a regression if you ask me. I'm currently looking at ways to possibly wrap the executable in a python script. One thing I'm having trouble with is binding to the server license in 10.1, when running from the command line.

Comment: They don't support it, but it can be done. The problem lies with EsriRegAsm for 64bit which does not work properly. Compile fo AnyCPU, generate the ecfg file for desktop, copy it by hand and use regular 64bit RegAsm. I hope this helps.